# How to replace all linebreaks with "\n" in a text file using sed?

Tags: sed

I have a text file and it's lines looks like this:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Line1\nLine2\nLine3
```

So I tried this command:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/n /g' myfile.txt | tee output.txt
```

But now the texts looks like this on the file.

```
Line1n Line2n Line3
```

Comment: Your replacement text should be `\\n` instead of `n`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, if you're using bash, something like `printf -v var '%q' "$(<file)"` might do.

Comment: @user8481790 : Please leave a comment about  your use-case. I can't see any practical reason to do this, but I know I've seen this exact same question (not from you) appear here in the last 2 weeks. Are you working thru an on-line course? And what do you think defines are line-ending in a *nix file? But ++ for a well crafted Q (with some code! gasp!). ;-)  Good luck.

Comment: Generally, if you want to keep line-endings in a variable value, i.e `wholeFile=$(< inputFile)`, then just dbl-quote the variable when you use it, ie. `echo "$wholeFile"`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in a comment, you have to substitute `\\n` for `\n`. `s/\n/n /` inserts just a literal `n` followed by a blank, and `s/\n/\n/` would be interpreted as a linebreak by many versions of sed and nothing would change.

Instead of looping and loading the whole file into the pattern space like

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' myfile.txt
```

you could also use the `-z` option that looks for NUL characters to separate lines, which effectively makes sed load the complete file as a single line (requires GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' myfile.txt
```

This does append `\n` at the very end of the file, though. That's technically correct, as every file is supposed to end with a newline, but if you don't want that, you can remove it:

```
sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g;s/\\n$//' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, (conceptually simpler than using `sed`'s branching logic), is to add `tr` to the mix, provided we know in advance there's some character like "`#`" that's *not* in *myfile.txt*:

```
# make a 'myfile.txt' for convenience.
printf 'Line%s\n' 1 2 3 > myfile.txt
tr '\n' '#' < myfile.txt | sed 's/#/\\n/g'
```

Demo, which feeds its input back to `printf`:

```
printf "$(tr '\n' '#' < myfile.txt | sed 's/#/\\n/g')"
```

Output:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

Comment: I'm assuming every line *should* end with `\n` of course.